# Implement k-medoids algorithm by supplying the distances between data objects and the medoids

Tags: c++, algorithm, cluster-analysis, data-mining, k-means

I've been trying to implement k-medoids in C++.
So far, I've come up with implementing k-medoids by supplying the number of clusters (or the number of seeds), [as described in Wikipedia's k-medoids page.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-medoids)

Now, what I'm trying to do is to implement it by supplying the distances, instead of the number of clusters.

Let me draw a picture. The two circles represent a cluster and dots are data objects. C1 and C2 are the seeds (medoids).

[image]

For example, if you supply "8 miles", each green line in the picture above has to be equal or lower than 8 miles. I've spent a lot of time in searching how to implement k-medoids by indicating the number seeds, but not the distances.

I'd appreciate if you'd give any advice.
(I said I'm using c++, but the programming language itself doesn't matter, since I'm concerned about the algorithm only.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you limit the maximum distance, you are doing **hierarchical clustering** (more precisely, a single cut through the cluster tree), not k-medoids.

It's common to do this with a distance matrix, too.